# Processing records with conditions in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given a pandas dataset with columns a, b and c, I have the following requirement:

```
calculate m = mean of c in the entire dataset

For each record in the dataset, if (a>10 and b<5) c = m
```

Is it possible to do this with a single pandas command, or I need to loop each record and ask the condition?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is very much possible using boolean masks

This should work-

```py
m = df.c.mean()
df.c[(df.a > 10) & (df.b < 5)] = m
```

Answer (score 0):

You would better use loc when trying to update a slice of a dataframe, to avoid the common error:

```
m = d['c'].mean()
df.loc[(df['a'] > 10) & (df['b'] < 5), 'c'] = m
```

Answer (score 0):

**One line**

```
df.loc[df['a'].gt(10) & df['b'].lt(5), 'c'] = df['c'].mean()
```